# How to run command using :norm?

Tags: execute

Why does `:norm :echo hi` echo hi ? How can I do something like that?

I would like to `:.,.+4norm :m5<cr>J`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this.

One is to use a literal `<CR>`:

```
:.,.+4norm :m5^MJ
```

with `^M` obtained by pressing `<C-v>` then `<CR>`. I am not sure if that `:normal` quirk is properly explained in the manual.

The other is to not use `:help :normal` at all because it serves absolutely no purpose in this context:

```
:.,.+4m5|j
```